# How to execute sqlcmd.exe using Windows Forms Application passing the proper parameters to the Prompt Line?

Tags: winforms, scripting, sqlcmd

Pressing a button in my Windows Forms Application I want the sqlcmd.exe to be opened and the following statement to be executed in it:

```
"sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql"
```

And I also want the script output to be written in a textarea in my Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Why bother with `sqlcmd` at all? You can simply use `SqlCommand` and provide query text from that one stored in your script.

Comment: Will this also return me the output of the script which I could write in the textBox of my WinForm Application?

Comment: Yes, it will return the output, and retrieval of this output is significattly easier than getting it from `sqlcmd`.